# Get records and send them in batches by an api- DataFactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have to update the data from a table in sql server with `65023` records to a post type api which takes 100 records in the body per batch, the endpoint is `https://api.local/batch/update` the body contains a batch of 100 records, the body is this

```
{ "inputs": [
     {
     "id": "{id[1]}",
       "properties": 
       {
         "field1": "{field1}",
 "field2": "{field2}"
       }
     },
     {
     "id": "{id[2]}",
       "properties": 
       {
       "field1": "{field1}",
 "field2": "{field2}"
       }
     }
....
]
}
```

where `id`, `field1`, `field2` correspond to the columns `id`, `field1`, `field2`. No more than 100 records can be sent in the body request, and all `65023` records must be sent How do I do it in azure data factory, thanks.

Comment: please share what you have tried.

Comment: When you use Rest api as a sink there is `writeBatchSize` option to write data in batches of particular amount you an set it as **100** for your requirement.

Comment: At the moment what I have done is: I have a "search" activity, which brings me the data from the table, when I get it it goes through a "foreach" and inside the idea would be to set the first 100 records in the activity type "WebActivity" pointing to the endpoint
I don't know how to take only the first 100 records in the "body" format and continue like this until they are all completed.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to update data in batches from SQL server to Rest Api with post method you need to set `writeBatchSize` option to write data in batches of particular amount you and set it as **100** for your requirement.**

- First select your source as SQL database and table.
  [image]
- Then select sink as rest Api and give your Api with post method and to write data in batches of particular amount you and set `writeBatchSize` as **100** for your requirement.
  [image]

**This is my Pipeline JSON for your reference:**

```json
{
    "name": "pipeline4",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                        "partitionOption": "None"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "RestSink",
                        "httpRequestTimeout": "00:01:40",
                        "requestInterval": 10,
                        "requestMethod": "POST",
                        "writeBatchSize": "100",
                        "httpCompressionType": "none"
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "RestResource1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**Reference:** [REST as a Sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#rest-as-sink)

Comment: Hello, how can I set the 100 records in the request body?
**{ "inputs": [
     {
     "id": "{id[1]}",
       "properties": 
       {
         "field1": "{field1}",
 "field2": "{field2}"
       }
     },
     {
     "id": "{id[2]}",
       "properties": 
       {
       "field1": "{field1}",
 "field2": "{field2}"
       }
     }
....
]
}**

Thank you

Comment: you need not to pass request body as you just need to map the objects correctly or it will take it automatically in request body.